# Assigning bash variable inside curl command for jenkins API

Tags: bash, variables, jenkins, curl

Searching stackoverflow and other google searches did not satisfy my question about assigning bash variable inside curl for the whole purpose of accessing jenkins API.

This is my simple script to access Jenkins API and it already goes wrong here:

```
JENKINS_USER=myUser
TOKEN=myToken
DOCK=myDock
HOST=localhost
PORT=8080

BASE_URL=https://$JENKINS_USER:$TOKEN@$HOST:$PORT/view/all/job/myProject/api/

curl -g -k ${BASE_URL}
```

Output from bash:

```
user@c012311:/mnt/c/Users/User/Desktop$ ./myScript.sh
./myScript.sh: line 6: $'\r': command not found
./myScript.sh: line 11: $'\r': command not found
curl: (3) URL using bad/illegal format or missing URL
```

I tried accessing my variables like so:

- \"$TOKEN\"
- ${TOKEN}
- '$TOKEN'

Yet the results are the same.

The results are preventing me from furthere progression my script for filtering my jenkins builds:

```
BUILD_NR=$BASE_URL/xml&xpath=//artifact/relativePath[contains(text(),$DOCK)])
```

And furthere more using those assigned variables inside other variables:

```
ARTIFACT=$BUILD_NR/[...]
```

**How do I correctly assign variables using bash and curl?**

Comment: Dbl-quoting the use of all variables (99.9% o the time) might help, so try curl -g -k "${BASE_URL}"` ... ``$\r` sounds like MS-Windows line endings causing a problem. Clean them with `dos2unix myScript` and then rerun. Good luck.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to @[shellter](https://stackoverflow.com/users/620097/shellter) for providing an answer for my problem.

I fixed this by adding double quotes to all variables like so:

```
BASE_URL="https://"${JENKINS_USER}":"${TOKEN}"@"${HOST}":"${PORT}"/view/all/job/myProject/api/"
```

Furthemore - by executing `dos2unix myScript` I dont get those annoying outputs anymore:

```
./myScript.sh: line 6: $'\r': command not found
./myScript.sh: line 11: $'\r': command not found
```

Answer (score 0):

Just run this script on Linux and seems to work fine, it connects to `https://myUser:myToken@localhost:8080/view/all/job/myProject/api/` it just throws a `Connection refused` since there is nothing on 8080 on my machine

I think the issue is line endings. Windows-style line endings (\r\n) - you need to change them to Unix style (\n), hence your error `'\r': command not found`. Try running the dos2unix command on the script file